# Expression meaning "as it certainly turned out"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I think there was a phrase that meant precisely that. The only thing that I remember is that it ended with ...*enough* (I'm not very sure, though).

Example:

> I glanced around to make sure I was still in the same room. And [...] enough,
>   everything still looked the same: the same wooden tables, the same...

Of course I could be mistaken. In that case I welcome other alternatives.

Comment: Well, there's *sure enough*,  or *lo and behold*, or *what do you know* (pronounced *whaddaya know*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use '*of course*':

> "And *of course*, everything  still looked the same..."

OED: "Of course - *used to introduce an idea or action as being obvious or to be expected.*"

Although, it seems you were thinking of what @Jim said - 'sure enough'.